# Facebook "Like" button don't work on Safari

Tags: javascript, facebook, safari

The like button works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. I haven't found reference to this issue on the web.

Please find the link [Test website](http://allvisio.com/test.html)

And the full web site link (in french only today) [allVisio](http://allvisio.com)

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer with a friend.

To see the button, you need to be connect to facebook with the navigator.
Logic but not easy to understand the first time